# Cant load material ui theme variables in storybook documentation

Tags: typescript, next.js, material-ui, storybook

Estou recebendo os seguintes erros no meu arquivo "preview.ts" ba pasta "storybook"

```
'ThemeProvider' refere-se a um valor, mas está sendo usado como um tipo aqui. Você quis dizer 'typeof ThemeProvider'?ts(2749)
type ThemeProvider = /*unresolved*/ any
```

```
O operador '<' não pode ser aplicado aos tipos 'boolean' e 'number'.ts(2365)
'CssBaseline' refere-se a um valor, mas está sendo usado como um tipo aqui. Você quis dizer 'typeof CssBaseline'?ts(2749)
type CssBaseline = /*unresolved*/ any
```

aqui está o meu preview.ts na pasta storybook (Estou utilizando Next.js)

```
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/react";
import { themes } from "@storybook/theming";

import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import theme from "../src/components/mui-theme/theme";

/* snipped for brevity */

export const withMuiTheme = (Story) => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Story />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export const decorators = [withMuiTheme];

const preview: Preview = {
  parameters: {
    actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
    controls: {
      matchers: {
        color: /(background|color)$/i,
        date: /Date$/i,
      },
    },
    backgrounds: {
      default: 'dark'
    },
    docs: {
      theme: themes.dark
    }
  },
};
```

Eu Tentei o que a documentação do Storybook recomendou nesse link: https://storybook.js.org/blog/material-ui-in-storybook/. Porém continuei recebendo os mesmos erros